# Как лучше всего вывести List <Music> list, где Music - это интерфейс?

Tags: java, ооп, переопределение

Есть класс `MusicPlayer`, у него есть поле `List<Music> list` , где **Music** - интерфейс с методом **скажиСвоюПесню()**, который реализуют три класса.

Если обращаюсь к этому списку через геттер, то получаю ссылки, а не объекты.

Так вот, подскажите, пожалуйста, надо у каждого класса, который реализует интерфейс,  переопределять  **toString**, чтобы получать текст? Или это можно как-то удобнее сделать?

Comment: ну если поведение для метода  toString одинаковое для всех, то можно сделать дефолтный метод в интерфейсе, с8 версии джавы это возможно

Comment: Насколько я понял, вам нужно получить текст не у `toString() `, a  y `скажиСвоюПесню() `. Или я не так понял?

Comment: Да, мне нужно получить у метода скажиСвоюПесню(). Просто я так понял, что нужно переопределять метод toString(), чтобы видеть именно название песни. Но я мог и не правильно понять, новичок же...